Spotfire- Scatterplot Line Connection Issue
I'm trying to figure out why Spotfire is having issues with making line connections on my scatterplot. All points of data have an x-axis for Days and a y-axis for Running Depth. All points share the same Well Name (or property name). Some points can be associated as moments of realized failure marked by the "x" shape, while most other points were not failures. My line connection is indicating to connect by Well Name, but whenever I have failure points, Spotfire line connection adds other lines. How can I get this to stop?   

Is it possible that there are not more lines, but the same line going back onto itself? If you show the line order with arrows maybe it becomes clearer. You could also try adding an explicit order to the lines

Yes, you're right. If I add arrows/direction to the lines, they point back to themselves. I'm not sure what causes this, but I cannot get that to go away. I'll have to find out how I can add an explicit order to the lines... maybe that will work.

The drawing order function seemed to solve this issue (recommended by Gaia Paolini)... I applied my column of Running Depth and this removed additional lines.
